# Binding results of two SQL queries by column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have tried  a lot of searching online and unable to find an answer to this. As an example, lets say I have two tables, Persons and Names with the following info (this is only for illustration and I don't have control over the DB structure)

```
Persons:
PID         FNameID        LNameID
1           100            101
2           102            103
3           100            103
...


Names:
NameID            Name
100             James
101             Baker
102             Thomas
103             Walter
```

Is there a simple query to obtain the following result, for a given person (PID) the first and last names and then combine them to display like:

```
PID      FName         LName
1        James         Baker
```

I looked at UNION, JOIN, nested queries, etc but couldn't figure it out. Feel like I'm missing something basic. Any help is appreciated. 
Wanted to add that I am able to get each name separately and combine with PHP, but I was hoping there was a Sql way of doing it (like UNION does it for row binding)

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`.  And `JOIN` again.

Comment: Yes, first join is to get your firstname from fnameid and second join is to get lname from lnameid. Hence 2 joins

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need two joins:

```
select p.pid, nf.name as fname, nl.name as lname
from persons p left join
     names nf
     on p.fnameid = nf.nameid left join
     names nl
     on p.lnameid = nl.nameid;
```

Comment: nf and lf seem a bit random .

Comment: @Gordon-Linoff: Thank you very much. Understood your hint, but still had not constructed the answer with the aliases and "ON" keyword. Greatly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT
p.PID, fname.Name as FName, lname.Name as LName
FROM Persons p
JOIN Name fname ON p.FNameId=fname.Id
JOIN Name lname ON p.LNameId=lname.Id
WHERE p.PID=1;
```

More about JOIN  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html